# jquery dropdown and text boxes don't work on ios chrome browser

Tags: android, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very basic search page with dropdowns and text boxes.

The snippet looks like following

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; max-width:0px;">
           <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Business Name</span>
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Parameters.BusinessName, new { style = "display: none;" }) 
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Parameters.BusinessName, new { @maxlength = 50, @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter a business name", @aria_describedby = "basic-addon2", @style = "width:350px;" })
        </div>

        <div class="input-group col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; max-width:0px;">
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Parameters.BusinessNameSearchType, new { style = "display: none;" }) @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Parameters.BusinessNameSearchType, searchtypes, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:150px;" })
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And on the page this snippet looks like following.
[image: How it looks on desktop, android tablet and android phone chrome browser]

I use bootstrap 3.3.5 and jQuery 2.1.4.

It works perfectly fine on desktop, android tablet, and android phone, when I use Chrome as a browser.

However, both textbox and dropdown break completely (break as becoming completely unusable) when I try viewing it on the newer versions of iPhone ios Chrome browser.

Interestingly enough, when I tried to emulate it in Chrome as the iPhone X, it worked fine as well.

I am completely new to the whole ios topic. Doing some basic research led me to believe that older versions of bootstrap/jquery might be the issue.

Trying to update to bootstrap 4, which also leads to updating jquery to 3.0.0, completely breaks the whole application, so I had to revert it back.

Before I dive too deep into fighting the whole bootstrap/jquery thing, can anyone please provide me any useful pointers to why ios is so picky? I want to get at least the basic understanding of what the problem is before I start digging into possible solutions.

Comment: `Vadzim` You want both **textbox** and **dropdown** in single row on mobile screen? I mean you don't want to break textbox and dropdown on mobile?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam I made my interface responsive, so it will move to the new line on smaller screens.

Comment: I had been write snippet for both large/small screens so check my snippet example.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam Thank you very much! I'll check it as soon as I get the chance!

Answer (score 0):

I have added two example with help of (**Bootstrap-4**) as your posted instruction.
1st - Break textbox and dropdown on mobile.
2nd - Not break textbox and dropdown on both Desktop & Mobile.

You can check below snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="py-3">
  <div class="container l">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Textbox & Dropdown (Break on Mobile Screen)</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 my-2">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">Business Name</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="Enter a business name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 my-2">
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option>Exact Match</option>
          <option>Option #1</option>
          <option>Option #2</option>
          <option>Option #3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <br><br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Textbox & Dropdown (Not break on Desktop/Mobile Screen)</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 my-2 pr-1 pr-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">Business Name</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="Enter a business name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-2 pl-1 pl-md-3">
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option>Exact Match</option>
          <option>Option #1</option>
          <option>Option #2</option>
          <option>Option #3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I feel like I worded my question wrong. I don't have a problem with fields breaking to the new line, responsive works fine in that regard. It's the textbox and dropdown themselves. They break and become unusable. I was trying to find the cause of it.